# MonoDroid 4.0.6+ on GoogleTV?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, google-tv

I've been trying to find out if MonoDroid can run on the GoogleTV as it uses an Intel Atom x86 CPU instead of a ARM CPU.

I came across:: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_For_Android_4.0.6

The release notes quote:: "It also includes x86 support for full versions of Mono for Android (not trial)".

Does this statement mean MonoDroid will now support GoogleTV??

If so i'm buying the software...

NOTE: It's not an issue if it runs in the emulator, only if MonoDroid can run on the native hardware.

Comment: Have you tried just asking Xamarin's support for an official answer?

Comment: Yes I am also asking them and waiting for an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should in theory, but it haven't been tested yet.  An upcoming release will add x86 emulator support to the trial version.  Or you can purchase, try it, and if it doesn't work, take advantage of the full refund.

Comment: Yep I think i'm going to do just that tnx.

Comment: Just got the chance to get it today.  I will let you know as soon as I get it working...  Or if I can't and why.

Comment: So far I can't get it to work as you can see from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148458/cant-get-monodroid-4-0-6-x86-emulation-or-googletv-to-work

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it will.  I think Mono usage requires the NDK, which Google TV does not have.