# Can't get MonoDroid 4.0.6 x86 Emulation or GoogleTV to work

Tags: mono, x86, xamarin.android, google-tv

First off all, i'm on OSX 10.7.3 using MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4 with MonoDroid 4.0.6 and Mono 2.10.9.

So I have purchased MFA and have created the generic "Mono for Android Application" project for testing.
I have checked the ABIs to "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a" and "x86" in the Advanced tab under Option/Build/MonoForAndroidBuild.
I have also set the build to release.
I then go to Project/CreateAndroidProject in the fileMenu to build my apk file I will use to upload to the Logitech Revue GoogleTV device or x86 Emulator.

After uploading and running the application I get the error::
"The Application AndroidTest(process AndroidTest.AndroidTest) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.".

I also get this same error when using the Android Emulator "API lvl 10 Intel Atom x86".
Has anyone got MonoDroid to work on any x86 platforms?  If so, which one and what were the setting you used?  Were you using VirtualBox or the standard AndroidEmulator?  Also what API level did you use and what were the MonoDroid proj/sln setting you needed to set to get it to work?
NOTE: The proj I used works on my ARM android phone device and the ARM AndroidEmulator.

I have also set the AndroidManifest.xml flag::

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

When I use "adb logcat" it gives the error on x86 emulators:: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:   799 cannot locate 'atexit'..."

**EDIT - Here is the logcat information when running the application on a Logitech GoogleTV::**
"

> I/ActivityManager(  193): Starting: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10200000
>   cmp=com.Reign.WaterDemo_Android/waterdemo_android.Activity1 } from pid
>   247 I/ActivityManager(  193): Start proc com.Reign.WaterDemo_Android
>   for activity com.Reign.WaterDemo_Android/waterdemo_android.Activity1:
>   pid=2084 uid=10060 gids={1015} I/ActivityThread( 2084): Pub
>   com.Reign.WaterDemo_Android.**mono_init**: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 2084): Shutting down VM W/dalvikvm( 2084):
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x66995778)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2084): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load monodroid:
>   findLibrary returned null E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):    at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2084):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:24)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:22)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3938)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3693)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3649)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:124)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2084):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4083)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2084):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) W/ActivityManager(  193):   Force finishing activity
>   com.Reign.WaterDemo_Android/waterdemo_android.Activity1 D/dalvikvm( 
>   193): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 324K, 18% free 9559K/11591K, paused 59ms
>   I/dalvikvm-heap(  193): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.816MB for
>   178700-byte allocation D/dalvikvm(  193): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 18%
>   free 9723K/11783K, paused 59ms D/dalvikvm(  193): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed
>   117K, 19% free 9606K/11783K, paused 58ms I/dalvikvm-heap(  193): Grow
>   heap (frag case) to 10.794MB for 1155900-byte allocation D/dalvikvm( 
>   193): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 18% free 10733K/12935K, paused 56ms
>   D/dalvikvm(  193): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 18% free 10733K/12935K,
>   paused 57ms I/dalvikvm-heap(  193): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.752MB
>   for 2054924-byte allocation D/dalvikvm(  193): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K,
>   15% free 12740K/14983K, paused 57ms W/ActivityManager(  193): Activity
>   pause timeout for ActivityRecord{66e1c680
>   com.Reign.WaterDemo_Android/waterdemo_android.Activity1} D/dalvikvm( 
>   193): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 15% free 12867K/14983K, paused 1ms+3ms

"

Comment: please add logcat for further debugging.

Comment: After using logcat with the IntelAtomx86_2.3.3 emulator image it gives the error:: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:   799 cannot locate 'atexit'..."  Don't have the GoogleTV with me at the moment, will post back its logcat output when I can.

Comment: @Megha Joshi: it looks like your (Google's, assuming you work there) atexit fix on the x86 ndk is not quite right, linking shared libraries still leaves them with this missing symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google TV does not support NDK, so the MonoDroid Java framework cannot load the libmonodroid.so library.  There are no ABIs that will work at this time.

There is a feature request open for NDK support on Google TV:

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=12

Comment: I was aware that the NDK didn't work on the GoogleTV, but 'libmonodroid.so' doesn't link to the NDK does it?  Its just a C lib the boots up mono/monodroid right?  Also monodroid only wraps java api's correct?  That shouldn't stop java from loading it, just because its a C lib.  I'm new to android so maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: `libmonodroid.so` is a native library which is built with...the Android NDK. (Any native library that does anything useful needs the NDK, just to use e.g. `libc.so`.)

Comment: Just wondering, but how do they get Java itself to launch then??  They don't need the NDK for that... Kinda irritating they made it so hard to use anything else but Java.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue which affects Mono for Android apps in all x86 emulators, and a fix for this is going to be included on the next release of Mono for Android. It's a bug in the Google x86 ndk which was supposedly fixed (but, it turns out, it isn't), so we had to do a little workaround. Debug builds of your app should work correctly, this should only affect Release builds.